# How to programmatically get questions from a Survey

Tags: column, spfield, survey-list, survey

The question is quite simple:

how can I get the list of questions from a Survey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Survey` list the question is a field. In order to determine whether field is a question or regular field you could utilize `SourceID` attribute, in case of questions its value is not `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get questions in Survey List 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="list"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<SPField> GetSurveyQuestions(SPList list)
{
     return (from SPField field in list.Fields 
                let fieldSchema = XElement.Parse(field.SchemaXml) 
                let sourceId = fieldSchema.Attribute("SourceID").Value 
                where sourceId != "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" 
                select field).ToList();
}
```

**Usage**

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
         var list = web.Lists[surveyName];
         var questions = GetSurveyQuestions(list);
         //print questions
         foreach (var question in questions)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(question.Title);
         }          
    }
 }
```

Comment: Worked awesome! How can I modify so I get the created date for each question?

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I found right now is this: checking the ShowInVersionHistory property of each field!

```
using (SPSite sito = new SPSite("URL"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = sito.OpenWeb())
            {
               var list = web.Lists["SURVEY LIST NAME"];

                foreach(var Field in list.Fields.Cast<SPField>().Where(x => x.ShowInVersionHistory))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Field.ToString());
                }
          }
   }
```

In my case, this will print all the Questions

Is there a better way to do that?